# Unique Count for Multiple timewindows - Process or Reduce function combined with ProcessWindowFunction?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We need to find number of unique elements in the input stream for multiple timewindows.
The Input data Object is of below definition InputData(ele1: Integer,ele2: String,ele3: String)
Stream is keyed by ele1 and ele2.The requirement is to find number of unique ele3 in the last 1 hour, last 12 hours and 24 hours and the result should refresh every 15 mins.
We are using SlidingTimewindow with sliding interval as 15 mins and Streaming intervals 1,12 and 24.
[image: Input Stream multiwindow processing]

Since we need to find Unique elements, we are using Process function as the window function,which would store all the elements(events) for each key till the end of window to process and count unique elements.This,we thought could be optimized for its memory consumption

Instead,we tried using combination of Reduce function and Process function,to incrementaly aggregate,keep storing unique elements in a HashSet in Reduce function and then count the size of the HashSet in Process window function.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#processwindowfunction-with-incremental-aggregation

```
public class UserDataReducer implements ReduceFunction<UserData> {
    @Override
   public UserData reduce(UserData u1, UserData u2) {
        u1.getElement3().addAll(u2.getElement3());
        return new UserData.Builder(u1.getElement1(), u1.getElement2(),)
                .withUniqueUsers(u1.geElement3())
                .createUserData();
}
}

public class UserDataProcessor extends ProcessWindowFunction<UserData,Metrics,
                                         Tuple2<Integer, String>,TimeWindow> {
 @Override
    public void process(Tuple2<Integer, String> key,
                        ProcessWindowFunction<UserData, Metrics, Tuple2<Integer, String>, TimeWindow>.Context context,
                        Iterable<UserData> elements,
                        Collector<Metrics> out) throws Exception {
        if (Objects.nonNull(elements.iterator().next())) {
            UserData aggregatedUserAttribution = elements.iterator().next();
            out.collect(new Metrics(
                    key.ele1,
                    key.ele2,
                    aggregatedUserAttribution.getElement3().size(),
                    ));
        }
    }
    }
```

We expected the heap memory consumption to reduce,since we are now storing only one object per key per slide  as the state.
But there was no decrease in the heap memory consumption,it was almost same or a bit higher.
We observed in the heapdump of the new process, a high number of hashmap instances,consuming more memory than the input data objects would occupy,in the ealrier job.

What would be the best way to solve this? Process function or Incremental aggregation with a combination of Reduce and Process function?

State Backend: Hashmap
Flink Version: 1.14.2 on Yarn

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'm not really sure if partial aggregation will reduce Heap size. It should allow You to reduce state size by some factor depending on the uniqueness of the dataset. That is because (as far as I understand) You are effectively copying `HashSet` for every single element that is assigned to the window, while they are being garbage collected, it doesn't happen immediately so You will see quite a few of those `HashSets` in heap dumps.

Overall, `ProcessFunction` will quite probably generate larger state but in terms of Heap Size they may be quite similar as You have noticed.

One thing You might consider is to try to apply more advanced processing. You can either try to read on Triggers and try to implement a trigger in a such a way that You will have 24h window, but it would emit results for ever y 1h, 12h and 24h (after which the window would be purged). Note that in such case You would need to do some work in `ProcessFunction` to make sure the results are correct. One more thing You can look at is [this post](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/07/30/demo-fraud-detection-3.html).

Note that both proposed solutions will require some understanding of Flink and more manual processing of window elements.

Answer (score 0):

You intent is right, even I would go for ProcessWindowFunction with Incremental Aggregation:

You can try to use some probabilistic datastructure like Hyperloglog(HLL) instead of costlier collection like Hashset(as its underlying implementation is HashMap)

There is a good read about [HLL](https://amitj975.medium.com/an-efficient-way-of-calculating-distinct-count-over-a-data-hyperloglog-a7481f0fcf3d), you can use using this considering:

- we have to count unique elements for a particular window
- no. of elements(not just unique, but total) in our window is quite large

Probably if you have less no.of elements in your window then you can consider HLL++ ; Google has come up with its own version of it called [zetasketch](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/40671.pdf); you can add as [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zetasketch/zetasketch/0.1.0) and you are good to go with estimating the unique elements.

> Algorithm:
>
> - as and when you encounter the element you add it to hll => hll.add(elem)
> - keep accumulating the unique elements in some datastructure in ReduceFunction => hll1.merge(hll2)
> - and finally count them in the ProcessWindowFunction => hll.result()

This datastructure is extremly fast and space efficient. Literally you can save some dollars in long run!

Would be happy to hear if this works!